Input/output manipulators and lambda capturing
I have the following code that compiles and works correctly due to such a concept as Input/output manipulators:
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

struct st{
auto mke(){
    return [](std::ostream& os) -> decltype(auto) {return os<<42;};
}
};

int main(){
    std::cout<<st{}.mke();
}

But actually, in my project, I need to capture this by reference and output some fields of the structure. Something like this:
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

struct st{
int a=42;
auto mke(){
    return [this](std::ostream& os) -> decltype(auto) {return os<<a;};
}
};

int main(){
    std::cout<<st{}.mke();
}

But it doesn't compile:
error: no match for 'operator<<' (operand types are 'std::ostream' {aka 'std::basic_ostream<char>'} and 'st::mke()::<lambda(std::ostream&)>')
   12 |     std::cout<<st{}.mke();

Q: I need a detailed explanation of the reasons preventing the compilation of the second example. What really happened?

I believe this boils down to A) lambdas with captures can't be cast to function pointers and B) the overload that makes the first case work with operator<< expects a function pointer. So really, this question is asking "how do I pass a functor to std::ostream::operator<<()?

It always helps to include the error message in the question

@alter_igel You're right, I have to update the question.

I often find that when I am trying to do something weird in C++ and the syntax gets wonky, then I am doing it wrong. What problem are you actually trying to solve with this construct?

Your first example works because the standard operator<< accepts a function pointer, and your non-capturing lambda is convertible to such a type.
Your second example fails because a capturing lambda is not convertible to a function pointer.
The typical way to solve this is to not use a lambda at all.  Return a struct/class object instead, and overload operator<< to handle that type, eg:
#include <iostream>
#include <ostream>

struct st {
    int a = 42;

    struct manipulator {
        st& m_st;
    };

    manipulator mke() {
        return {*this};
    }
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const st::manipulator &io) {
    return os << io.m_st.a;
}

int main(){
    std::cout << st{}.mke();
}

Online Demo

In the first example, overload resolution looks at all the various operator<< that are defined in the global namespaces and in std, and finds basic_ostream& operator<<(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>& (*func)(std::basic_ostream<CharT, Traits>&) );. This is a viable overload because there exists a conversion from non-capturing-lambda closure-object to pointer-to-function (of a matching signature).
In the second example, the function pointer overload of operator<< isn't viable, because the closure object of a capturing lambda doesn't have a pointer-to-function conversion.
